# Last names with suffix in the same field filters out and does not display

Tags: sql

I have a table with first, middle, and last name.  In the last name field the suffix appears (which is correct).  However, when I create a query referencing that table, and run the script, the last names with the suffixes does not show.   It is as if they are being filtered out of the list. How can I get a the names with the suffixes to appear in the new table? Any assistance will be greatly appreciated

```
FName      MName       LName
Bobby        B          Bond II
Johnny       J          Jones Jr.
```

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Can you post the query?

Comment: Your question is unclear.. please post ur sample input and desired output..

Comment: are you 100% sure this was the query and not `Select distinct LName  FName, MName From Employees` (comma missing after LName)?

Comment: Show your query. Also: which DBMS are you using? And which SQL tool? Some tools might truncate values for display purposes