# Last names with suffixes in the same field is filtered out and does not display

Tags: sql

I have a table with first, middle, and last name. In the last name field the suffix appears (which is correct). However, when I create a query referencing that table, and run the script, the last names with the suffixes does not show. It is as if they are being filtered out of the list. How can I get the names with the suffixes to appear in the new table? Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

See example below…

```
Employee table - this is how the data appears
FName      MName       LName
Bobby        B         Bond II
Johnny       J         Jones Jr.

Select distinct Last_Name, First_Name, Middle_Name, EmpID
Into Employee_Dept
From Employees emp Join
     Department dpt
     On emp.EmpID = dpt.EmpID;
```

Desired output – I want the suffixes to display in the Employee_Dept table as in the reference table, but it is filtering these names out of the list.

```
EmpID FName      MName       LName
110   Bobby        B          Bond II
220   Johnny       J          Jones Jr.
```

Comment: How is this different to your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40247990/last-names-with-suffix-in-the-same-field-filters-out-and-does-not-display

Comment: That one is now closed. (Duplicate of this one.)

Comment: I resubmitted because the data was not displaying correctly.  Thanks,